# Some icons files are missing in iOS app after submitting it to App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I have used @3x icon files in my iOS application.

For example: If the icon file name is '`sampleIcon@3x.png`' then I'm creating `UIImage` as follows:

```
UIImage *sampleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleIcon.png"].
```

I have tested the app in simulator and iOS devices as well. All icons files are appearing fine. I have submitted it to AppStore. Once AppStore approved it, for some users some icons files are not showing for some reason.

Why this is happening? Is there any issue with iOS, I'm sure iOS is Perfect. I think, I'm missing something in my App.

I need your valuable suggestions.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are the "some reasons"? Version of iOS or different Devices? 
You have more targets in your project?
You have all formats: .png, @2x.png and @3x.png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. **@3x** images will not work in **iOS7**. So, if you want to develop app only for **iOS8** then you can use only **@3x** icon files, in else case you need to include both **@2x** and **@3x** icon files in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You should clearly check the images are appearing correctly go to build Phases->copy Bundle Resources and check any of the images are red in color just delete them .Otherwise delete all icons and right click on your navigator and go to Add Files to "Your App" now select the icons you needed.Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks @Suneha. Actually the problem is with 3x icon files in iOS7.

Comment: Yeah @Suneha ..I just Added 2x icons also to the project.